# How to dynamically close bracket while typing using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I've seen questions here regarding this same problem except asking how to *configure settings for a text-editor.* I want to know how to do this in the browser using JavaScript inside an `input` element or a `textarea` element.

To expand a little more, while typing, if a user presses `(`, `<`, `{`, or `[` I want JavaScript to automatically put a closing element `)`, `>`, `}`, `]` according to the one typed, preferably fast enough to add it before the user is likely to type another character.

I'm not *that* experienced with JavaScript so I'm coming here for help. Here's what I've tried:

```
$(".editable").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 219) { // open bracket
        $(".editable").val() += "]"; // close bracket
    }
});
```

But it throws an error <kbd>Invalid left-hand assignment</kbd> Also, this seems like a problem which could have a more efficient/elegant solution/approach to what I tried? Any help would be much appreciated.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/94VNT/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix the syntax error, change

```
$(".editable").val() += "]"; // close bracket
```

to

```
$(".editable").val($(".editable").val()+"]"); // close bracket
```

But this is a cheap solution which

- would apply the change to all `.editable` inputs, not just the one in which you type
- doesn't take into account the position of the cursor (you may type at another position than the end)
- acts (on keydown) before the value is changed

Here's a better version, also putting the cursor *between* the brackets, and working on parenthesis and curly brackets :

```
(function(){
    function insertInto(str, input){
        var val = input.value, s = input.selectionStart, e = input.selectionEnd;
        input.value = val.slice(0,e)+str+val.slice(e);
        if (e==s) input.selectionStart += str.length - 1;
        input.selectionEnd = e + str.length -1;
    }
    var closures = {40:')',91:']', 123:'}'};
    $(".editable").keypress(function(e) {
        if (c = closures[e.which]) insertInto(c, this);
    });
})();
```

I use `keypress` to better handle key combinations (on some keyboards, `keyup` wouldn't easily distinguish between `[` and `{`). And I've put everything into an IIFE to avoid polluting the external namespace.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/oqetAReg/4/)

Comment: You should remove the first solution, because it is seriously buggy if there is more than one `.editable` element on the page. Or at least replace it with `$(this).val($(this).val()+']');`

Comment: val() accept a function as parameter, would be better to use it but i guess you know it ;) `$(".editable").val(function () {
    return this.value + "]"
});`  But 'your better' version is better for sure

Comment: @JaceCotton I added the insert at cursor position.

Comment: @dystroy Yes I saw that, thanks a lot! I changed `input.selectionEnd = e + str.length` to `input.selectionEnd = e + str.length - 1` that way the cursor goes between the two brackets typed (opposed to the end). I don't suppose that'd cause any bugs?

Comment: @JaceCotton No, that's fine, in fact I had the same idea, see demonstration :)

Comment: @JaceCotton New version more extensible, just in case ;)

Comment: @dystroy Everything works well except for the brace (`{`). When I type one, it inserts a closing bracket (`]`). I guess some keyboards can't differentiate between a key with shift and a key without?

Comment: @JaceCotton did you check the last version (the one using keypress) ?

Comment: @dystroy Yes, I tried `keypress` but then nothing would work.

Comment: @dystroy I got it to work! For some reason it started working for me when I added another keycode for `<`.

Comment: As jsbin.com is down, I made this : http://jsfiddle.net/8QkQ4/ All the friends I asked had it well working

Answer (score 1):

Since we know you are going to be applying this method for a number of possible keystrokes, I'd recommend converting your keydown callback function into a `switch`:

```
$(".editable").keydown(function(e) {    
switch(e.which) {
    case 219: //open curly bracket
                this.value += '}';
        break;
    case 188: //less than
             this.value += '>';
        break;
    }
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/D9g3F/

Comment: This doesn't work on my keyboard : it puts a } if I type a [. See my answer for explanation.